# Python: Calculating the inverse of a pseudo inverse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to calculate the pseudo inverse of a matrix which should be not very difficult. The problem is inverting the matrix.

I am using the following code:

```
A=numpy.random.random_sample((4,5,))
A=mat(A)
B=pseudoinverse(A)

def pseudoinverse(A):
    helper=A.T*A
    print helper*helper.I
    PI=helper.I*A.T
    return PI`
```

to test this I included the print line. helper*helper.I should give unity. The output I get from this is:

```
 [[ 2.    -1.     0.     0.     3.   ]

 [ 0.     2.     0.     0.     3.5  ]

 [ 0.    -0.5    1.125 -1.     2.25 ]

 [ 2.     0.     0.25  -2.     3.   ]

 [ 0.     0.     0.5   -2.     4.   ]]
```

which is clearly not unity. I don't know what I did wrong and really would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix `A` does not have full column rank. In consequence `helper` is singular and not invertible (If you `print helper.I` you will see some very large numbers).

The solution is to compute the *right inverse* instead of the *left inverse*:

```
helper = A * A.T
PI = A.T * helper.I
```

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Definition) for more details.

Unless you are doing this for exercise, you could also use [numpy's built in implementation of the pseudeinverse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html).

**edit**

```
>>> numpy.random.seed(42)
>>> a = mat(numpy.random.random_sample((3, 4)))  # smaller matrix for nicer output
>>> h = a * a.T
>>> h * h.I
matrix([[  1.00000000e+00,   1.33226763e-15,   0.00000000e+00],
        [ -1.77635684e-15,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00,   1.33226763e-15,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Up to numeric precision this looks pretty much like an identity matrix to me.

The problem in your code is that `A.T * A` is not invertible. If you try to invert such a matrix you get wrong results.
In contrast, `A * A.T` is invertible.

You have two options:

1. change the direction of multiplication
2. call `pseudoinverse(A.T)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip with pinv. This works fine. Nevertheless, I would like to get my function running.
I should have paid attention in my linear algebra classes. Your code does not work because the rank of the matrizes you multiply. Further, I do not want to change the direction of the multiplications...
Even in your code helper*helper.I is not unity. Don't ask me why

Comment: @Glostas When I try `helper*helper.I` the result is unity (see edited answer).  Maybe there is another problem hidden somewhere?